# How to replicate the launch image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

My main app has to do some work in a webview, so I want to keep the launch image up longer while this work takes place. To do this, I created a controller with a UIImageView and I'm loading the Default image up in it:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"Default"];

// These all tend to fill the screen, but end up distorting the image
//self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
//self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

// This keeps the aspect the same, but doesn't fill the screen
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

This mostly works, except when the real launch image goes away and is replaced with mine, I have two white bars - one at the top and one at the bottom - where the image doesn't completely fill. I've tried to set the contentMode to the various fill/fit's, and even though this has the desired effect of filling the full screen, it stretches and distorts the image slightly.

So what I'm wondering is - what does the launch image do that I'm not doing? How can I replicate the display exactly so that the user can't tell it's a different image?

Comment: What are the sizes of your imageView and the displayed image ?

Comment: @A-Live I've got a Default, Default@2x and a Default-568h. Image size shouldn't be a problem though if the Launch process can use the same thing and display it full screen.... right? I've proven also that the imageView does fill the full screen, but not without distorting the image.

Comment: Please provide the numbers, it should make the answer obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Like in your project I use a launch image and then in the first UIViewController called I have an UIImageView inside. The image resolution, must be exactly the same as the screen's definition.
The code in the UIViewController is something like this :

```
CGRect fullFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

// Img Background
UIImageView *background;
if (fullFrame.size.height <= 480) {
    background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-480h.png"]];
}
else if (fullFrame.size.height <= 568) {
    background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-568h.png"]];
}
else if (fullFrame.size.height <= 668) {
    background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-668h.png"]];
}
else {
    background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-736h.png"]];
}
background = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, fullFrame.size.height);
myMainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[myMainView addSubview:background];
self.view = myMainView;
```

I check the different screen size depending on the iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6 plus.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I can't use the Default, Default@2x and other Default.png files (i.e, launch images)?

Comment: Absolutely not, you can use the same file. You can use the Default and Default@2x in your images.xcassets for the launch images and use them too in the UIViewController's background.